# Ruby blocks to change scope to specific variable

Tags: ruby

I'm a complete newbie in ruby but I can feel that this code can be improved.

```
    class LoginPage < BasePage
       def initialize(session)
         @session = session
       end

       def login(params)
         @session.within '#login-form' do
           @session.fill_in 'Login', with: params[:login]
           @session.fill_in 'Password',with: params[:password]
         end
       @session.click_button 'Login'
       end
     end
```

I was thinking to do something like:

```
@session do 
  within '#login-form' do
    fill_in 'Login', with: params[:login]
    fill_in 'Password', with params[:password]
  end
  click_buttton 'Login'
end
```

But this code won't work. Any idea how to change scope of these method calls to make them calls to specific instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `instance_eval`.

```
@session.instance_eval do  
  within '#login-form' do 
    fill_in 'Login', with: params[:login] 
    fill_in 'Password', with params[:password] 
  end 
  click_buttton 'Login' 
end
```

However I'd argue that this makes your code confusing to read since one could easily miss the `instance_eval` when scanning through the code.